# Tactics to speed up WKWebView rendering of loadHTMLString-d content?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I've been experimenting with stacking WKWebViews in a UINavigationController as a method of making a hybrid app that's more native than PhoneGap. It broadly works - I hook into decidePolicyForNavigationAction when a WKWebView hits a link, and push a new ViewController with the link it wants.

But the page loading is slow. I've done everything I can think of to speed it up - it's using loadHTMLString rather than a request to ensure everything is local - I've even tried stripping out the CSS and JS to see if that speeds it up, but no dice. It still takes at least 500ms for a short, HTML only, locally stored page to appear in the empty WKWebView. I can tell from debugging that the delay is not in reading the HTML from disk, but the time between loadHTMLString() and didFinishNavigation().

Does anyone have any tactics for fixing this? I'd try to preload the view, only I don't know which link the user is going to tap so I don't know what to preload.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

Both WKWebView and UIWebView delays on first run. It is more visible when using WKWebView. I have implemented class which warmups web views to resolve this issue. You can find Swift version of this solution here: https://github.com/bernikovich/WebViewWarmUper

**Original answer:**

Looks like WKWebView/UIWebView delays on first run. I've created simple class for boosting loading speed of web view with warming up. You can try sample project: https://github.com/bernikovich/NSTViewWarmuper (not available any more)

Answer (score 3):

An interim answer - I am having some success creating the next view in advance, then using `evaluateJavaScript` to run `document.body.innerHTML = "content"` - it does not have the half-second delay. Of course, it means creating a WKWebview earlier than I would otherwise, but hopefully that isn't a performance killer.

Comment: For me creating static variable to create WKWebView once, and preloading it worked

Comment: @green0range can you guide how ekzactly you did it.

Comment: @iMinion Actually I ended up not using static variable for WKWebView because it was causing more troubles than gain, and I realized that WebView was sufficiently fast when it was on real device instead of simulator.

Instead of static variable though, I did create an instance variable for WKWebView per view controller, and initiated in viewDidLoad, and it worked fine for my use cases

Comment: @green0range  actually i hav a tableview with wkwebview in each cell n on tap of cell the cell expands to full content of wkwebview at that time there is a delay n user can actualy see the previous content n then the new contends load , if u can just paste ur code here which helped you

Comment: @iMinion here's my answer on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59940783/2697217

Answer (score 0):

My way is to go less native and more web. 
1. Work out a single page app, like http://m.ftchinese.com/phone.html
2. Bundle every resources (JS, CSS, Graphics as Base64) into one file. 
3. Save that file to my Xcode project and use that file to launch the app, setting the baseURL as http://m.ftchinese.com/phone.html

The code here:

```
let templatepath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html")!
let base = NSURL(string: "http://m.ftchinese.com")
var s = NSString(contentsOfFile:templatepath, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error:nil)!
self.webView!.loadHTMLString(s, baseURL:base)
```

This has some benefits: 
1. I've already worked on the web app for many years so it's very stable. 
2. The same approach can be used on Android, Windows Phone and Blackberry. 
3. SPA has No paging loading. It feels very smooth.