# WKWebView loads local html slower than UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have `UIWebView`, `WKWebView` and `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` to load local HTML but `wkWebView` is slower than `UIWebVIew`. What is the reason? How can I improve the rendering speed?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have the problem too. there is a solution by Timur Bernikowich:
https://github.com/bernikowich/NSTViewWarmuper

But, `WKWebView` is also slower than `UIWebView` with using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` method.

For more see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42109186/5557953

Comment: I have Swift version of this demo: https://github.com/bernikowich/WebViewWarmuper

Comment: Tried to integrate this, but did not help

Comment: However creating static variable that gets initialized once worked.

Answer (score 0):

Short but adequate solution: Disable phone number data detectors for you WKWebView (enabled by default if you use Storyboard).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53527592/1683141

Answer (score -1):

Disabling `WKWebView`'s data detectors worked for me. Swift version:

```
let webViewCofig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webViewCofig.dataDetectorTypes = []
webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: webViewCofig)
```

To enable specific data detector, pass the specific type as .address,.link etc while setting dataDetectorTypes:

```
config.dataDetectorTypes = [.address]
```