# WKWebview iOS - Slow on first launch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am displaying a simple html page using WKWebview. When I first click a button to navigate to that controller with the WKWebview, it hangs for few seconds and then opens. This happens only for the first time after app launch.

Message in console: `[Process] WebContent process (0x127060f00) took 3.816507 seconds to launch`

I use this code to navigate to the webview controller.

```
let webviewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "webview") as! WebviewController;
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webviewController, animated: true)
```

How to avoid this delay?

Comment: A long delay from the moment *pushViewController* is called until the page is actually displayed, can be caused if you have a time-consuming operation going on in the view controller's "View Will Appear" method. Do you have something like that?

Comment: No. There is no operation in viewWillAppear. In viewDidLoad, I set the url to the webview. There is no time consuming operation

Comment: OK. If I were you, my next step would be moving the line that sets the url to "viewDidAppear" and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tactics to speed up WKWebView rendering of loadHTMLString-d content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684558/tactics-to-speed-up-wkwebview-rendering-of-loadhtmlstring-d-content)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the same approach as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42109186/6385925). It seems to be enough to do this once anywhere:

```
let webView = WKWebView()
webView.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil)
```

That eats the delay of the first launch and when you launch your actual view it's faster. I've implemented it to start after the app launched:

```
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
...
}


class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func woraroundInitialWebViewDelay() {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil)
    }

    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil
    ) -> Bool {
        woraroundInitialWebViewDelay()
        return true
    }
}
```